# SqlCeException when attempting to delete rows from table in sdf database (Corruption?)

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce, sql-server-ce-3.5

I attempt to delete a number of rows from a table in a SQL Server CE 3.5 database and I get a `SqlCeException`:

> An internal error occurred. [ ID = 3649 ]

I've read that it means that the database is in a corrupted state and must be repaired although there is little information about the specific error.

I use the `SqlCeEngine.Verify()` and it returns `true`. According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0a5czch(v=vs.90).aspx)

> Returns True if the checksums match and there is no database corruption; otherwise, false.

I also use the `SqlCeEngine.Repair(null, RepairOption.RecoverCorruptedRows)`;
and then attempt to delete the rows again and the command is executed without any errors and rows are deleted.

I'm confused is it or not the db corrupted? I think it is (but the verify returns true). If it is corrupted how it became corrupted? I create a new connection for every database access and I don't share the same `SqlCeConnection` objects between threads (or any other SQL Server CE related objects) The database is deployed on a mobile device.

Comment: First make sure you are running the latest SQL Compact engine build on the device: http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2010/08/sql-server-compact-35-sp2-downloadable.html

Comment: @ErikEJ I updated the device to the SP2 and then SqlCeEngine.Verify(VerifyOption.Enhanced) returned false. After reading your blogpost and http://erikej.blogspot.gr/2010/10/how-to-detect-sql-server-compact.html I installed the cummulative update 7 and reinstalled sqlce cabs too, but ServerVersion returns `"3.5.8080.0"` is it correct?